# Zend_Acl and Zend_Navigation not working with module name as resource

Tags: zend-framework, module, zend-navigation, zend-acl

I have setup Zend_Acl to work like this:

```
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'));
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('user'));
$acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('frontoffice'));
$acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('backoffice'));
$acl->deny('user');
$acl->allow('user', null, 'frontoffice');
$acl->allow('admin');
```

So the role 'admin' has acces to everything, 'user' has only access to frontoffice.
Frontoffice is the name of a module and backoffice is the name of a module. The Acl is checked in a custom plugin:

```
<?php
class Custom_Controller_Plugin_Auth extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    $loginController = 'auth';
    $loginAction     = 'index';

    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

    // If user is not logged in and is not requesting login page
    // - redirect to login page.
    if (!$auth->hasIdentity()
            && $request->getControllerName() != $loginController
            && $request->getActionName()     != $loginAction) {

        $redirector =     Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Redirector');
        $redirector->gotoSimpleAndExit($loginAction, $loginController);
    }

    // User is logged in or on login page.

    if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
        // Is logged in
        // Let's check the credential;
    $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
        $acl = $registry->get('acl');

        $identity = $auth->getIdentity();
        // role is a column in the user table (database)
        $isAllowed = $acl->isAllowed($identity->role, null,
                                     $request->getModuleName());
        if (!$isAllowed) {
            $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Redirector');
            $redirector->gotoUrlAndExit('/');
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

Now, the name of my resource is the name of the current module. If I plug the acl into Zend_Navigation, and set the resource of a menu item to frontoffice, the menu item disappears both for user and admin, but they both should be able to view it. This is the navigation code in the bootstrap:

```
protected function _initNavigation()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();
    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($this->getOption('navigation'));
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $role = $auth->getIdentity()->role;
    $view->navigation($navigation)->setAcl(Zend_Registry::get('acl'))
                      ->setRole($role);
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can't define directly modules in ACL. You have to define each controller of each module using the following syntax:

```
$this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource("module_name:controller_name");
```

Comment: Well, I don't want to use that notation because I have a simple system that should only use the module name to regulate access. My Acl is working fine via my plugin, it just doesn't play nice with Zend_Navigation.